# Lambda generic type bounds

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I have the following method:

```
    public <T> T getObjectFromMessage(Class<T> clazz) {
        return gson.fromJson(compressor.decompress(message.getJsonInputs(s3)), clazz);
   }
```

I want to pass `getObjectFromMessage` as a parameter into a lambda that's supplied to me.  The lambda can then supply the class of the object that it expects to find in the message, and get an instance of it back.  Is there a way to do this without losing the type information?

I can force it to work with casting and some Object bounds, but I'd really like the consumer to know that if it passes in a `Class<T>` it will get a `T` back, much like any method with generic bounds.

In the consuming lambda, I'm currently forced to do declaration gymnastics like:

```
public void consume(Function<Class<Object>, Object> getInputs){
    MyType type = (MyType)getInputs.apply(MyType.class);
}
```

but there are cases where I want to try to parse the inputs, and if I fail, try a different class.  The generics really need to be inferred per-call, as a method would.

Comment: I would have thought it would be `Function<Class<?>, ?>`, because only `Object.class` has type `Class<Object>`.

Comment: Can you show the context of the call to `getObjectFromMessage`?

Comment: Using Object as a type bound does not seem to be a bound

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a custom function interface with a generic method:

```
interface TypeFunction {
    <T> T apply(Class<T> clazz);
}

public void consume(TypeFunction getInputs) {
    MyType type = getInputs.apply(MyType.class);
}
```

Comment: Why genericize the method instead of the interface?

Comment: @LewBloch Genericizing the interface would lock `getInputs` to  a specific type. OP wants it to return `T` for any `Class<T>`.

Comment: Which it would do in a lambda, just as it does in, say, `Function<T>`.

Comment: @LewBloch Why don't you try?

Comment: If you use the <T> in the interface, it would force the user to create a new instance of TypeFunction every time there is a different Class<T> if you leave it in the method one instance of TypeFunction will suffice.

Comment: @VinceEmigh No.

Comment: Leave a concrete method in the interface?

Comment: Genius!  This solved my issue perfectly.  I had just about resigned myself to casting everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts on this... does a function that invokes another function add anything?

For example:

```
<T> T consume(ReadType<T> typeFunction) {
    T type = typeFunction.read();
    return type;
}
```

There are generic types being managed in at least 3 entities here:

1. The class that contains the message string.
2. The function that deserializes the message string to an object.
3. The function that calls the deserializer function.

I expect from the question that the Object that holds the message string is also responsible for deserialization? If so you could consider declaring the generic type there. That would prevent the need of passing the type to the deserializer function, for example this could be simplified further:

```
<T> ReadType<T> readObjectFromMessage(Class<T> clazz) {
    return () -> readValue(clazz);
}
```

I've declared `ReadType` as:

```
interface ReadType<T> {
    T read();
}
```

Also implemented a simple test to check outputs and visualise how this might be used:

```
@Test
public void consumeTypeTest() throws Exception {
    String message = "{\"foo\":\"hello\",\"bar\":\"world\"}";
    GenericFunctions genericFunctions = new GenericFunctions(message);

    ReadType<MyType> myTypeFromMessage = genericFunctions.readObjectFromMessage(MyType.class);
    MyType myType = genericFunctions.consume(myTypeFromMessage);

    Assert.assertThat(myType, equalTo(new MyType().setFoo("hello").setBar("world")));
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of hidden complexity in the rest of the code that would make adding the generic type param to the class that owns the message pretty ugly.  The implementation you have here, where the owning class holds the generic type, is what I'm migrating away from--because in this case I need to change the type but maintain backwards compatibility with the previous type until all my old servers are out of service.  But this is shared code, so adding e.g. another type param for a second possible input type would be pushing ugliness downstream to all the derived classes.